# Error en app Flutter en la API level 29 (Pie) de android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, samsung

Tengo un [Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime 2](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_j7_prime_2-9135.php) que actualmente posee la versión 9 de android. Cada vez que creo un proyecto nuevo con flutter va todo bien no me lanza errores en la creación, al momento de poner la app en ejecución es donde recibo el siguiente error:

```
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Security exception: Permission Denial: forceStopPackage() from pid=20133, uid=2000 requires android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: forceStopPackage() from pid=20133, uid=2000 requires android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:8694)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runForceStop(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:967)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:197)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:20233)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:642)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:540)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:3447)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:4174)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\allan\Documents\DeveloperProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: Security exception: Permission Denial: runInstallCreate from pm command asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: runInstallCreate from pm command asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
    at com.android.server.am.UserController.handleIncomingUser(UserController.java:1827)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.
Error launching application on SM G611M.
```

---

Ya he pasado varios dias intentando encontrar una solución, he llegado a la conclusión de que es mi dispositivo ya que lo he probado en otros y funciona perfectamente. Hago resaltar de que la aplicación es la que se crea por defecto con flutter, sin modificaciónes ni nada.

Agradeceria mucho si alguien me pudiera orientar, o explicar si tengo que hacer algun tipo de configuración especial en mi disposito o algo, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: que error más raro, habilitaste tu dispositivo en modo debug? no tienes algun permiso especial para aplicaciones desconocidas?

Comment: @diegoveloper si mi dispositivo tiene el modo desarrolador, depuración usb, modo debug etc, todo lo tiene habilitado, permisos especiales para aplicación tambien las tiene habilitadas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba agregando este permiso en el `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"></uses-permission>
```

Si con eso no funciona, realiza estos pasos:

- Desinstala la app
- Deshabilita y habilita las opciones de desarrollador
- Re-habilita USB Debugging
- Reinicia el teléfono

Comment: Ya habia provado hacer esto y tampoco funciona, el error perciste.

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta, intenta esos pasos

Comment: SI me funciono muchisimas gracias me has salvado eres un pro. Muchisimas gracias enserio.